# Five day forecast for loop not returning data

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, for-loop

I've been working on a project that requires me to get a five day forecast, but when I try to get the for loop to return the five day value, it's only returning the information for the last day five times.  This is the code I have:

```
function displayWeatherFiveDay(weather) {
    for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {
        var fiveDayTemp = weather[i].temp.day;
        var fiveDayHumid = weather[i].humidity;

        console.log(fiveDayTemp, fiveDayHumid);

        for (var q = 0; q < 5; q++) {
            document.getElementById("img" + (q + 1)).src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" +
                weather[i].weather[0].icon
                + ".png";
            document.getElementById("daytemp" + (q + 1)).innerHTML = "Temp: " + Number(fiveDayTemp).toFixed(1) + "°";
            document.getElementById("dayhumid" + (q + 1)).innerHTML = "Humidity: " + Number(fiveDayHumid).toFixed(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Is it because I have a second for loop nested in there?  I'm not sure why that would only return the last item in the array though.  Any feedback will help, thanks!

Comment: I think you are not using outer variable "i", somehow you can use it with Id.
What are the data that you get inside weather  object

Comment: that was exactly the problem, the second loop was forcing the first one to be ignored.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using outer variable "i", somehow you can use it with Id. What are the data that you get inside weather object